# iPhone Lightning Dock Model A1717 not supported by iPhone XS Max

Tags: iphone, ios, dock, lightning

I just bought an **iPhone Lightning Dock Model A1717** (**08/2019** says on the box) and I want to use it with my **iPhone XS Max**, but I get the error:

> This accessory is not supported by this device

iPhone **iOS 13.4** - just updated. Both the **iPhone** and the **Dock** are **original** **Apple**

---

I have tried to restart the iPhone while connected to the accessory - **no effect**

I have tried to switch to Airplane mode while connected to the accessory - **no effect**

I have cleaned the lightning port from my phone and dock lightning jack - **no effect**

Comment: Could be a cable issue. Are you using an Apple-branded lightning cable? If so, to you have another Apple-branded cable you can test with?

Comment: @IconDaemon I tried with both Apple-branded cable and a different manufacture cable, I also tried from different sources - power bank, MacBook, power socket. Unfortunately the same result. This is the second dock that gives me this error, I have sent first back thinking is faulty.

Comment: just spoke with an Apple consultant and there is nothing that will solve this, unfortunately

Comment: Can you add that as an answer?  Just saying 'consider this closed' doesn't close the question.  Adding and accepting the answer will also help other people who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not to sound flippant, but we (or I) can’t provide you support beyond what Apple’s going to provide so if they consider it “closed” we can’t go beyond that.  However, I can advise you what to do next:

1. Return it from where you purchased it (it may be defective)
2. Ask someone at *Apple* (on-line sales via phone or chat, or in person at the Apple store) what models the Lightning Dock is compatible with.

   - Ask them if there is a compatibility list.
   - Ask them if it works with your specific phone
3. If you get satisfactory answers, purchase it.

If it fails again, open a customer service inquiry and escalate. (If you do the pre-sales question via chat, you’ll have a record).  It may be completely incompatible with your phone and its a perfectly valid, albeit horrible, response/answer.

If you happen to be in store, *open the box, hook it up, and make sure it works in font of the sales associate.*. Tell him/her exactly what you’re doing and why.  At the very least Apple will be made aware of the deficiency, but most importantly, you’d have saved your money rather than fork over $40USD to a company worth a trillion dollars.